# Reading bunch of data from a server

Tags: android

i have a short question and it would be awesome if someone could give me some directions. I have a listview and an editText field. When I start writing I want fill out the listview with data obtained from some database. Like imagine I have a bunch of addresses somewhere. When I enter "a" I get bunch of addresses that start on a. I know I could use TextWatcher and Filter, I just need to know how to implement the communication between my app and database.

Thanks.

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter` with setup `FilterQueryProvider`, SimpleCursorAdapter implements `Filterable` interface so you can use `getFilter().filter()` to filter-out your data

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner to making Android backends I would recommend you look into [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as a backend. It is easy to get started and there is a lot of sample code, especially for listviews. It is less-easy to shoot yourself in the foot so to speak with a backend as a service like Firebase and it is rather popular now.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a cursor adapter to populate the listview. Now to filter the content based on the user input you could use searchview with listview.

Here is a good tutorial :

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/01/create-searchview-filter-mode-listview-android/

Comment: the link you posted uses an `ArrayAdapter`, not a `CursorAdapter`

Comment: I just posted this link so he/she can get in an idea, how searchview with listview can be used. It doesn't matter really that this tutorial uses ArrayAdapter.

Comment: yes, it does, if his data model is sqlite database he should use a `CursorAdapter`, not an `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: He should use CursorAdapter obviously hence it was mentioned very clearly in my answer. Do I need to write a new tutorial to make sure that he gets the complete solution without doing anything ? If yes then you are most welcome to do it.

Comment: you don't need to post any tutorial, simple: `when searching use adapter.getFilter().filter()` would be enough, but OP already said `"I know I could use TextWatcher and Filter"`, what he doesn't know is the whole filtering process and by default `CursorAdapter` does not filter anything: you need to setup `FilterQueryProvider` on it, or (if extending `CursorAdapter`) override `CursorAdapter#runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint)`

Comment: Hi, I was more curious about the way how I should store bunch of addresses in a file (that is not in a phone) and when user starts writing, I make some connection to my storage and populate the list. So, the question is more how to make an internet connection to my storage.